# Badge points are colorless

Tags: bug, badges, meta

Consider:

[image]

I just noticed the badges don’t have any color. Does someone else experience this?
On the main site I do not have an issue.

It also applies to the badge section of my profile:

[image]

Comment: Might be your cache. I can see the badges.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks, have found an answer, but not the reason.

Comment: [Well...](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [VLAZ said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421876/badge-points-are-colorless#comment937234_421876) he doesn't experience the issue, I had updated my Firefox browser from 106.0.5 64 bit to 107.0.1 and they reappeared.